# calculating age in years and weeks in java using calendar object

Tags: java, calendar

i am calculating age in years and weeks if current year and dob year is same it should answer in weeks but my code is not working it show only when i input two different years

```
if (dob.get(Calendar.YEAR) != now.get(Calendar.YEAR))
{
    if (dob.get(Calendar.MONTH) > now.get(Calendar.MONTH))
    {
        age--;
    }
    else if (dob.get(Calendar.MONTH) == now.get(Calendar.MONTH))
    {
        if (dob.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH) > now.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH))
        {
            age--;
        }
        System.out.println(name + "is " + age + " years old");
    }
}
else if (dob.get(Calendar.MONTH) < now.get(Calendar.MONTH))
{
    age++;
}
else if (dob.get(Calendar.MONTH) == now.get(Calendar.MONTH))
{
    if (dob.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH) > now.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH))
    {
        age++;
        System.out.println(name + "is " + age + " weeks old");
    }
}
```

Comment: I suggest you lay it out properly with consistent braces `{}` and indentation, and then your logic might be easier to follow.

Answer (score 0):

In your `else` statement, you're only printing something if:

- the "now" month is the same as the "dob" month
- the "dob" day of the month is greater than the "now" day of the month.

As @khelwood suggests, adding braces `{}` would help you see this clearly.